# Prove that the set $\beta$ = {$O(K,U)$ | $K \subset X$ is compact, $U \subset Y$ is open} is a subbasis.

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$,$Y$ be topological spaces and $C(X,Y)$ be the set of continuous maps $X \rightarrow Y$. If $K \subset X$ and $U \subset Y$, define $O(K,U)$ to be the set of $f \in C(X,Y)$ such that $f(K) \subseteq U$.

Prove that the set $$\beta = \{O(K,U) \mid K \subseteq X \text{ is compact }, U \subseteq Y \text{ is open}\}$$ is a subbasis for a topology on $C(X,Y)$.

Comment: Most of the question is totally irrelevant to the solution: Any collection of subsets of any set $S$ is a subbasis for a topology on $S$.

Answer (score 1):

I concur with David's comment: **any** collection $\mathcal{S}$ of subsets of a set $X$ forms a subbase for some topology on $X$. (We generate a base for that topology  by taking *all* finite intersections from $\mathcal{S}$, including the nullary intersection which equals $X$, etc.)

But Munkres decided in his popular textbook to demand that $\bigcup \mathcal{S}=X$ to avoid the question of nullary intersection (i.e. the convention that $\bigcap \emptyset = X$ in the context of subsets of $X$). So then we only need to remark that picking any point $p \in X$, $O(\{p\},Y)=C(X,Y)$ so the union of all subbasic elements $\beta$ is the whole set $C(X,Y)$ under consideration.